# Spring.net WCF service and multithreading: manage count thread for exec WCF method

Tags: .net, multithreading, wcf, spring.net

I'm create WCF service using spring.net. I need manage count threads which execute one method of WCF service. Example, method can execute only 3 clients and when 4-th client try execute menthod I need throw Exception "Not allow execute". Any ideas for my problem?

Answer (score 1):

Better to use WCF throttling in the binding configuration in this scenario.